# callback are executing multiple times react native

Tags: react-native

someone please tell me how to fix this issue , this function is calling multiple times , i don't know why and it is so annoying to fix

```
function NewProduct({ navigation }) {
  const supplierApi = useApi(suppliers.getSuppliers);
  useEffect(() => {
    supplierApi.request();
  }, []);
  return console.log(supplierApi);
}
```

the log is like below...

```
    {data: Array(0), error: false, loading: false, request: ƒ}
    {data: Array(0), error: false, loading: true, request: ƒ}
    {data: Array(0), error: false, loading: false, request: ƒ}
    {data: Array(0), error: false, loading: false, request: ƒ}
    {data: Array(7), error: false, loading: false, request: ƒ}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function as follows, this will same as `componentDidMount` for class component.

```
function NewProduct({ navigation }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const supplierApi = useApi(suppliers.getSuppliers);
    supplierApi.request();
    console.log(supplierApi);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: @shadyshamel Are you still getting the console statement multiple times?

Comment: i have got it , it return multiple times by default in react native
i left the debugging mode and added console.log , it worked good

Comment: Can you please share a little bit more code, as far I know this must run only once as the dependency array is empty?